# Instalar o Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 alongside Windows 7.  I was able to upgrade to version 11.04.
Now I'm trying to update to version 11.10 but I get an error message saying it is not possible to upgrade.

I decided to install a partition, but when I start the PC I don't get a grub screen that lets me choose which OS to boot. I formatted the partition where I installed Ubuntu, I've been looking for tutorials where you learn how to install Ubuntu on a partition part to try to understand the problem.

I wonder if anyone can explain how to install Ubuntu on a partition an existing partition, so that when I boot the PC I see the grub menu that lets me choose which system I want to start.

Comment: Go for fresh install of ubuntu 11.11 if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Use Wubi, or, on the installer, select to install alongside Windows 7.