# How to format a partition with ext3 on Windows XP for dual-boot Ubuntu-Windows XP?

Tags: dual-boot, ext3

The Ubuntu dial boot tutorial says:

> a GRUB boot partition 100 Mb -- formatted to filesystem type ext3
>
> a logical partition for the / (root) folder of each planned Linux (or
> Mac) OS (at least 10 Gb each, but 20-50 Gb is better) -- formatted as
> ext3 (or ext4 if you are planning to use a newer Linux OS)

But how to format `ext3` type? Windows XP doesn't offer this type. Only FAT32.

Comment: Windows does not understand `ext3` or `ext4` file systems so you can't format from Windows.  However the installer can create the partitions it needs see [Dual boot windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/148881/107450) as suggested by Radu.

Comment: What tutorial are you following ? I advise you use the official documentation and, IMO, there really is no need for a separate GRUB or boot partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I read from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes. Your link is really helpful, thanks.