# Ubuntu installation (multiboot)

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a windows 7 Computer.  I want to install ubuntu.  I know if I install to the unallocated it will set up the multiboot like it should.  However, I want to set the partitions up manually, I want different stuff in different partitions, e.g. logs.  If I do this, will the installer still set up the multiboot like it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes. The installer will take care of everything.

The long answer: when you select to install with "Something Else" Ubuntu takes care of the boot loader automatically, as opposed of previous versions where you could select if use GRUB.

You may look at this questions to solve any other doubt:

- [How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows 7 using “Something Else”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/163962/169736)
- [Dual boot windows Xp and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/148881/169736) (please read carefully since this includes a answer that will delete all your partitions)
- [How do I set up a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/107538/169736)