# Installation of Ubuntu(12.04, Intel Extreme graphics2) on a Dell XP desktop

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

I'm a Senior and not very computer literate and need detailed help in installing Ubuntu.
I do have the download in my Firefox/download file as an ISO image file. What to do, not wanting to crash the XP?
T.I.A.

WOW, can't even respond to this onslaught.
Seems to me that installing Ubuntu, which BTW failed, regardless NEEDS to still enable XP,,,, which I want to get away from = MS, that is.
Still need help in doing so.

Comment: if [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) doesn't help, you could check [this wikihow post](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some helpful links I have found to help with the installing Ubuntu 12.04. This setup is to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP, meaning you will have both operating systems on your computer. Make sure you have another computer with internet access around so if you any questions you can ask us, because while the Ubuntu 12.04 is installing you won't be able to use XP on the Dell to browse the Web.

First use this link to put the ISO you downloaded on a CD:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Than follow this any of these links to install Ubuntu 12.04. They talk about the same installation process just in different ways.

http://www.wikihow.com/Dual-Boot-Windows-XP-and-Ubuntu

[Dual boot windows Xp and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148881/dual-boot-windows-xp-and-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: thanks much, will tackle it tomorrow since I need to borrow a LT from a neighbor and then also find some CD's where to put it.Will let you know of the progress - LOL