# HELP ASAP I want to install ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

I want to install ubuntu for my pc but i dont want to lose my windows. I want to install both OS on my pc. How can I do it and how can i download the OS? please reply. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you visit the Ubuntu homepage, there's a nice orange button, labled "Get Ubuntu now". Click that button and select the correct architecture for your system. If you don't know, just stick with the recommended options.

Please read these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) for installing Ubuntu alongside an existing Windows installation.

Please please please read this document thoroughly before you begin. If you have any further questions, the Ubuntu wiki is a great resource.

Again, please read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Download it from here

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Check the [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the downloaded ISO image

Either create a [Live Cd through Burning it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows) or a Live USB through [Universal USB installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or through [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) , from windows.

[**First** try Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop) through above Live Media , before installing.

Read these guides and follow them for Installation procedure.

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

[Illustrated Dual-Boot instructions](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html)

Answer (score 0):

To download Ubuntu, visit www.ubuntu.com, then click "Get Ubuntu now." I'm going to assume you want the desktop version, so click "Ubuntu Desktop."

Now, if you want an easy way to try Ubuntu and get just about the full experience, just a tiny bit slower, scroll down and click "Windows Installer."

Otherwise, you need to first select either 64bit, or 32bit, if your computer is somewhat old, choose 32bit, otherwise, you are probably safe with 64bit. Click the orange button labeled Start Download, and wait for it to finish.

Then, go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-windows for instructions on burning an Ubuntu CD or DVD or http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows to use a USB (if your computer is older, or you want the easiest option, you should use a CD).

Once done, insert the CD and turn off your computer, turn it back on, and allow Ubuntu to boot. Follow the instructions until you get to the installation prompt. Choose "Install Ubuntu Alongside Them" to keep Windows and install Ubuntu.

Move the slider to choose how much of your hard disk each OS will use. Click install and then follow the installation steps (It's easy stuff like "choose your region" etc).

You'll then receive a prompt telling you to restart...

Welcome to Ubuntu!