# A "dummies" guide to dual-booting with Windows XP?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

I am learning EVERYTHING including how to cope with my own PC currently running XP.

I have downloaded Ubuntu onto a cd and have had a quick try out.
I would now like to install Ubuntu on a separate partition so I can learn how to work with it **before** I get rid of Windows entirely.

Should i use the Windows installation app, or is there another different/better option?

> **Note:** I am a 60 year old housewife and don't have teenagers in the house to ask for translations from Computerese to English.
>   Please give easy-to-understand answers! Help for "dummies" would be appreciated.

I currently have 2 partitions in my hard disk. The secondary empty one has 46 GB free.

Thank you!

Comment: Virginia, please look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/107539/58612) in the very similar "duplicate" question linked above. It has a step-by-step guide, with screenshots, on installing a dual-boot Ubuntu. Since you have an empty partition with sufficient space, and are taking the plunge into the Ubuntu pool, I would recommend doing a "proper" dual-boot installation instead of using the Windows installer (a.k.a. "Wubi"). Welcome to Ubuntu and AskUbuntu.com!

Comment: Thanks to both answers - one question - why do i have to set up a new user account to so the job??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install Ubuntu in Windows installer (Wubi). Plenty of info is located at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Then if you still prefer windows, you can very easily get rid of the Wubi installation.

I have done it in my old (>10 years) laptop and it is still running very smoothly.

However, for full capability, I suggest later to remove Wubi and make either a clean Ubuntu install or, alternatively, if you want to keep windows, a dual boot with windows XP.