# How to partition HDD and dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7 (first installed win7)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, root, home-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

**Hello'World'!**

I am coming from another planet (Windows planet) but i'm friendly and i hope you are also !?!
I recently bought a new hardware (a laptop) because i got accepted at a good Computer Science University in my country .
I also heard that we're going to study Linux alot so i thought why not getting started with it . I tryed some Virtualization in Windows for Kubuntu 8.x(an older version)  and now Ubuntu 12.04 .

For a few days now i'm getting more into Linux, and i decided to not just use it in VirtualBox. 
So i kept on this new machine, when i partitioned it,  some unallocated/free space (as you see from the screenshot) to install Ubuntu on it .( Note that i allocated for other partitions the exact size that i wanted by using 1GB=1024 MB -joke :) ).
http://s17.postimage.org/kr0mtkhfz/Capture.png

Now, even though i'm a tourist here , i managed to do a live usb for ubuntu and some additional repair tools on it if necessary.

But when it comes to how to partition the 100.66 GB left i'm blocked out. Here's what i want to have :

- a partition with Ubuntu installed - which i want to make it PRIMARY (the forth and last one i can) but i don't know how much space should i use (for Windows 7 on C: i kept 50 giga)
- the required partition for system repair  or Ubuntu creates this automatically?
- the swap partition and size more or even 4 gb RAM , should i go more than 4 GB ? Windows's page file is bigger but i wanted to shrink it anyway
- the partition where to keep most user files/games/kits i don't remind exactly but is this called home/ partition ? Should i make it fat32 so i can make this a "shared with win partition" ?

OH MY GOD when did i wrote so much text ?!?! ...
Please , if you're still here, tell me your opinion about how should i allocate the free space considering what i said before

Answer (score 1):

If you have three partitions already, the best course of action is to create an Extended Partition with the remaining Linux logical partitions inside.

Since you already have an extended partition, there is no problem creating as many logical partitions as you need from the unallocated space in the picture.

If I understand correctly you should create:

- A root partition for Ubuntu (/). This should be ext4, or whatever the current default is.

  - A home partition for Ubuntu (/home). You should NOT use fat32, since it is a really old system with many problems. A better choice is **ext3** -- there are windows drivers with read/write support that exist for it (http://www.fs-driver.org/ is one).
  - A swap partition (swap space). This is necessary for linux, and should be the same size as your RAM.

These are pretty much standard.
Hope that helps!

semitones