# Ubuntu Vs. Win 7

Tags: 12.04, boot, partitioning, windows-7

I had Windows 7 installed previously on my PC, but I mistakenly had compressed my boot files so I had to install a new OS. Since I didn't have the Windows install, I went a head and installed Ubuntu 12.04, hoping to install windows later.

Anyway, when I've got a Win 7 CD I tried to boot from it but it didn't work(the computer booted in Ubuntu). Later I tried removing Ubuntu from my PC by using the Ubuntu CD, but even after I removed it, the Win 7 CD didn't work.

I wondered whether there was something wrong with the Win 7 CD.  However it proved wrong as the CD worked when I opened it in Ubuntu using Wine loader. I tried to install it through that window (which may seem to you as stupid, but heaven knows I had no choice).

Unfortunately, it didn't work either. Then I tried partitioning the Hard drive through my Ubuntu CD, but it didn't work and I don't understand it well as I'm new to Linux.
Do I have to partition my Hard Disk?  If so, how?  Or else, Is there any other way to do this?

I'd be very grateful if you could help me. I like Ubuntu in many ways, but still I have a number of problems when coping with my day-to-day work in Ubuntu.

Waiting for your answers with fingers crossed!

Comment: Do you have your BIOS set to boot from CD?

Comment: You need to reinstall Windows, then install Ubuntu. Try [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/q/107538/12864), it's basically a duplicate of your issue. To get started installing Windows, you need a Windows disc and you need to [set your BIOS to boot from that disc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

Comment: First configure BIOS to check for CD as first boot device. You can access to that settings by pressing `F12` or `F2` or `Del` key depending on BIOS maker. Then boot Windows CD and install and then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info), so that we know your exact situation.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a number of problems when coping with my day-to-day work

Perhaps you should first try to get help for your other problems, and then had no need to install Windows anymore. What are your problems with the every-day work in Ubuntu?

Anyway, if you definitely want Windows, you should find out how to boot the CD. Normally, you should see some popup when booting that says " Boot selection" or similar, where key is F2, F8, F11, F12 or something else. Try that one and then select your CD-/DVD-Drive in the next dialogue.