# I dont' know how to install?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

I've downloaded the USB version from the web site, and the USB Installer, then I run it and it finished, but then nothing happens, I tried to go to ISO and run the setup then It finished and restarted the computer with Windows, Iv'e tried to restart it again and choose Ubuntu but it launches a black screen with some texts and nothing happens, please help me I'm very new to Ubuntu and I need to download it because my Windows is pretty awful!

Answer (score 0):

So AFAIU you have created a USB-installer http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. You don't need to run anything from your ISO image. Instead you need to restart your PC and boot from your USB stick. There you will see the installation menu.