# Dual booting Ubuntu on Windows 7 from E:// drive

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

I am planning on installing Ubuntu 12 on top of Windows 7 as a dual-bootable system. I have completely emptied the **E://** drive, equaling to almost 80 GB of free space. I want to install Ubuntu on this drive (thus leaving only the **C://** and **F://** drives for Windows). With reference to [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) article, can anyone tell me which stage would let me choose the **E://** drive as the space where I want to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Once you leave the 80 GB **unpartitioned** (i.e. not only format but also delete the partition) the Ubunut installer will choose this partition to install. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows

Comment: How to unpartition the E://drive?

Comment: Only after unpartitioning will E show up as an option? Which option (2nd one, or the Something else) do I have to select for getting that?

Comment: *"Something else"* will let you delete partitions, repartition drives, break your Windows and more. In case you are not experienced with Ubuntu and Linux filesystems it may be a better idea to do this from Windows in the first run and let the installer perform its auto-magic.

Comment: E drive is already a partition, right? Then can't I choose it as the space for Ubuntu?

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/92066/5538 -- Choose "*Install ubuntu alongside windows*". Image in step #5 shows that you can **select the drive**.

Comment: But I don't want to install alongside, I want dual-boot.

Comment: Ok, so first I unpartition **E://**. Then when will Ubuntu give me the option to select that 80 GB of unpartitioned space for installation?

Comment: Which figure (as per the linked article) I will get the option in?

Comment: Please see the accpeted answer in the question medigeek mentioned above. If you have unpartitioned your E:// partition you specify what space to use in step 5, if you haven't removed the partition yet, you can choose *Something Else* in step 4. Installing beside means the same thing as setting up dual-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/92066/5538

Choose *Install ubuntu alongside windows*.

Image in step #5 shows that you can **select the drive**.

It won't be labeled as "E:", but if you know the type and size of your disk/partition, you can surely identify it.

There might be an option to choose "Entire partition" or "Entire disk", as seen here: https://askubuntu.com/a/92066/5538

[image: ubuntu install ubuntu alongside windows -- entire partition or entire disk]

Comment: Like I told you, i don't want to install Ubuntu alongside, I want dual boot.

Comment: @Cupidvogel Ubuntu alongside windows and dual boot are practically the same term/thing. :)

Comment: Ummm, then why do they give 2 options (first and third) for the same thing?

Comment: *Something else* is more advanced. It allows you to define and make your installation **more custom** (to define and repartition more drives, e.g. swap partition). *Ubuntu alongside windows* allows you to choose the drive and install ubuntu. It's **easy and quick** and can be done without knowing much about linux-related partitions. That's the difference.

Comment: Thanks. There is a Windows Installer link in the article you pointed to. Will that do the entire dual boot process without the need for an `iso` image on CD/USB?

Comment: **No**. Windows installer is commonly referred to as the "**wubi installer**". It does not dual boot, it installs ubuntu as a "virtual" installation, i.e. it creates its files inside the ntfs partition, without repartitioning the drive and without creating linux partitions. That is good if you want to try out ubuntu, but wubi has [some disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29#Limitations) and is generally not recommended. **Dual boot** installs ubuntu in different partitions -- it's much faster and more stable.

Comment: So the first option will enable me to install Ubuntu on a drive of my choice, then I can dual-boot with either OS, and Windows will not show that drive in its list of available drives, right?

Comment: **Try it**. Burn ubuntu on a cd or create a live usb. Try the process and see if the first option works as explained. And correct, after you install Ubuntu, Windows does not support linux partitions and Windows will not show the "E:" partition/drive in "My computer". But Ubuntu can recognize ntfs drives, so you can keep a common ntfs partition (You mentioned "F:" partition) that can be used for exchanging files between Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

***Note:  When dealing with partitions, always make sure that you have a full backup of your system just to be on the safe side.***

Because you will be choosing/creating partitions manually, the option you want to select is Something else.  It starts at the Installation Type screen, and goes through choosing and/or editing the partition.  Make sure that you choose the right partition.

[image: Choose this First]

According to the link that you included in your question, it would be the second Installation Type screen, where it lists all the available partitions.

[image: Choose this Second]

Keep in mind that the partition will not be labled as E:/ but as sd(x), where (x) is the partition number, and it will show empty next to it.

***Note: Since you already have free unallocated space on the hard drive, you do not have to go through this partition resizing process.***

Images  compliments of [linuxbsdos.com](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/)

Comment: After selecting **Something else**, where will I get the option to specify the entirety of the **E://** drive for the installation?

Comment: But the 2nd option is for replacing the entirety of Windows 7 by Ubuntu!

Comment: Make sure that you choose **Something Else**

Comment: Yeah, that I'll do. What next?

Comment: Wait a minute, in you answer you asked me to choose the 2nd option, in your last comment you are asking me to choose the 3rd one!

Comment: Why is the C:// drive showing in this picture, but not the other drives?

Comment: What picture are you referencing?