# How to install ubuntu on win7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up a dual boot Windows  and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

I have Windows on my laptop and i want to install Ubuntu 12.4 (Precise Pangolin) also... I want to have a dual boot laptop... my problem is that i reached the maximum number of partitions in my laptop... is it okay to install it with "install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7"?

What are the risks of installing it on same partition?

Sorry for the trouble... I just don't know how to do it... Thanks :)

Comment: What does your partition layout look like? I know it needs two partitions for Win 7, but what else is on the drive?

Comment: @Githlar i have 2 for win 7 and the other for files... the other one is a hidden partition no drive letter... i have an unused/unallocated partition and i can't format it because i reached the maximum number of partitions.

Comment: well to the one who vote down my question "thank you!!!"... i'm not a genius on this... if you think this question is pathetic just mind yourself!!!

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: @Catholicus, No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Format the free space an "Extended" partition. This will allow you to add four additional partitions inside that Extended partition. There's no repercussion for doing this. Back on 7.04 I used to have my Ubuntu installed like this.

Another option is to run Wubi.exe from the disk while in Windows. This will (as far as I recall) place an Ubuntu folder at the root of the drive with a file that acts as the filesystem for an Ubuntu installation. It also adds an entry to the boot.ini file so that when you boot Windows you have the option of either booting Windows or Ubuntu (Both of which physically exist on the Windows partition, but are logically separate). This will require enough space in the Windows filesystem to install Ubuntu (roughly 2.5G I think).