# Is Ubuntu a distro with Nautilus included?

Tags: nautilus

This is what I'm told to download "You will need a working Linux Distro with Nautilus". I've never used Linux and know nothing about it.

I've got a Windows 8 on my computer. Do I make this a dual boot system, and can I install it to a USB 3 32Gig Flash Drive and run it from that?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question (the other question is already covered in more than one place on this site), yes, Ubuntu includes Nautilus, which is part of [Gnome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME), which is what Ubuntu is based on.

Comment: For windows geeks, Easier to think about explorer.exe as `Gnome` and File Explorer as `nautilus`. hahaha

Comment: @Smile "File explorer" *is* `explorer.exe`.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ File explorer is a subset of explorer.exe (there are lots components that running with explorer.exe), like I said easier to think because nautilus also known as a default file manager for Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

`nautilus` is, as the [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/nautilus/info) tells you, a file manager, and in fact the standard file manager for ubuntu.

So, this means: Yes, Ubuntu is a distro with `nautilus`.

As for your second question, please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/) explaining how to set up a dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu, or the [ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) for instructions on creating a bootable USB drive.

Comment: The goal seems to be a usb install, not a full install.  A dual install is more time consuming than to use a live disk to facilitate a usb install, which is safer for a newbie and less time to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

[Download an Ubuntu iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download), but not a KDE version (or Nautilus won't be installed).

Burn it to dvd.

Reboot computer with dvd in driver.

Now, you have Linux without installing.  Give it a test drive.

Nautilus is the program used to find files.  It's that window that pop up that allows to navigate in and out of directories and see files that are in them.  You can drag and drop files to other windows.

If you want to install to a usb:

1. Boot Ubuntu DVD, or if already running Ubuntu live go to next step,
2. open terminal.
3. enter: `sudo apt-get` update
4. enter: `sudo apt-get usb-creater` (hit tab to see which is for your system before hitting enter)
5. Finish with this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: This does not address the main question but instead answers a secondary question which is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: First, 'a working linux distro' may be a live one, with nautilus.  I addressed that.  Secondly, the goal seems to be to create a usb install.  A live disk can facilitate this, and is a safer method that committing to a full install since this person is obviously a newbie to Linux.