# Is "install alongside windows" the same as Wubi?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

When installing Ubuntu from a LiveCD on a Windows system, the following options are available:

- Install Ubuntu alongside Windows *XP/Vista/7/8*
- Replace Windows with Ubuntu
- Other

Is "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" the same as Wubi or is it a real dual boot?

*EDIT: I seem to have caused some confusion, I am not asking what the difference is between a Wubi install and a regular dual-boot install, I am asking if the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option creates a Wubi install or a regular dual-boot one.*

Comment: @hhlp Nope, I know the difference between Wubi and a regular install. I am just asking if the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option creates a Wubi install or a regular dual-boot install.

Comment: your another question is already answer here ->   [how do I set up a dual boot windows and ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu/107539#107539)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a real dual boot ;) you need to free up a partition and if you want to use swap, then you need to create a swap partition too ;)

Comment: Ok. So there is no way to create a Wubi install from a CD?

Comment: What do you mean by "CD"? you mean installing when you are booting from CD? then I have to say no. `wubi` is just for using in windows

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a wubi install creates a file in a windows partition and then boots from that. If you wiped windows you might lose this file.

When you install alongside windows, you're really installing it as its own, completely independent OS. You could remove the windows partition and ubuntu would be unaffected.