# Cannot find "Run Ubuntu alongside with windows" option when installing

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have Windows 7, and I'm trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. However, when I try to install Ubuntu with a USB, it doesn't give me the option to dual boot. I can only "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu", or "Something Else".

I've installed Ubuntu on this computer before, and this option was present. What I'm asking for is a way to get that option, or how to use the "Something else" option.

Answer (score 1):

How many partitions do you have. If you happen to have 4 primary partitions, then Ubuntu will say to replace your existing Windows since there are no more primary partition slots left (The maximum is 4 primary partitions).

Check to see if this is the case and decide which partition you wish to remove or change to a logical partition.

The explanation (With images) can be found in [Is it possible to have Windows 8 and Ubuntu on the same hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282250/is-it-possible-to-have-windows-8-and-ubuntu-on-the-same-hard-drive/282253#282253)

The answer should give you an idea of how to remove one of the primary ones and create a logical one which can be extended to several partitions.

Comment: When I go into the "Something else" option, i see sda 1, 2, 3, and 5

Comment: @Jason That means you have 4 primary partitions. Going to put the explanation here.