# Ubuntu alongside WIndows 7 - no option

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I can't install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 Professional 64bit, because I don't have the installation option.
I set up the partitions as shown in this picture:

[image]

Help me please

This is how Ubuntu sees the HDD:
[image]

Comment: You're installing from the CD or using Wubi or something like that?

Comment: I'm installing from the CD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find "Run Ubuntu alongside with windows" option when installing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298437/cannot-find-run-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-option-when-installing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [During Ubuntu Installation: No "Alongside Windows 8" option and "Use something else" only shows 500GB free space (no other /dev/)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578487/during-ubuntu-installation-no-alongside-windows-8-option-and-use-something-e)

Answer (score 3):

From what I see there you want to install Ubuntu on that 30 GB free space. Boot your PC from Ubuntu CD and choose `something else` when prompted to select partition. In the list click on your free space and then click the plus sign button to add a partition. Choose a size slightly larger than your RAM and select `At the end` option and use as `Swap`. Click Ok.

Now create the main partition by clicking the plus button again, but this time select `ext4 filesystem` and `mount point` as `/`. Check the `Format` box.

That's it. Click `Install Now`.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ) is a good tutorial.

Comment: In the list I have only free space 500GB. I'm afraid that if I will choose the new partition, then I remove the data.

Comment: @user271470 it must say 30 GB free space at the last item in the list, not 500 GB. That is your entire HDD. Yes you will lose data. Can you update your question with a photo of your screen?

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img843/8356/i9mm.jpg
There isn't 30GB free space.

Comment: Do not choose the 500 GB space or you will sure lose all your data!