# During Ubuntu Installation: No "Alongside Windows 8" option and "Use something else" only shows 500GB free space (no other /dev/)

Tags: system-installation

I have trouble installing Ubuntu, which I want to be alongside Windows 8. There is no alongside option but only the 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' option and also 'Use something else'.  It is as if my disk is empty without any Windows 8 OS.

I know that I can install it using the 'Use something else' option... by creating a partition in the Windows 8. By shrinking and get the unallocated 20GB free space partition (at which I already have currently) and I also know when I exceed 4 partitions, then the installation won't work, so now I only have:

- C:partition 175GB NTFS,
- E: partition 270GB NTFS,
- System reserve partition 350MB NTFS, and;
- also 20GB unallocated partition (I made for Ubuntu).

But when I boot Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, pressing F12, I then have both the 'Try Ubuntu' and 'Install' options.

When I click 'Install', I still don't have the 'Install alongside' option. Instead 
I only have the 'Erase and install Ubuntu' option.

Also, when I click on 'Use something else', it only shows:

```
Dev/
 Free space 500 000 Mb.
```

As if there is no primary partition. Because normally it would show:

```
dev/ sda1 ntfs
dev/ sda2 
dev/ sda3
```

So I am afraid to proceed because the free space I made was, and should be, 20GB and not the whole 500GB.

I need help. 
I've been searching all over internet and I couldn't find a problem that is the same as mine. I would really appreciate any help. Frankly, I'm really tired of using the 'Try Ubuntu' option.

P.S. My Windows 8 was installed by PC technician when my laptop was reformatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer eventually, the types were all basics. But the solution is here [Re: 'Install alongside' not available while trying Dual Boot with Win7 64bit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604074&page=4&p=10022223#post10022223) . Even I'm a bit hazy about that GPT but anyway yeah it worked perfectly. I am now able to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

Well anyway, thanks Dale A. for your suggestions.

Comment: If you could include the steps in your answer that would be great, in case the link dies at some point in the future.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 1):

Do the 'Try Ubuntu' to boot in to the live disk, and then open up the partition manager (Gparted) to see what partitions are really on the drive.

Or go back in to Windows, winkey+x to bring up the little menu of options from the Desktop, go in to Disk Manager and do the same thing.

Make sure there are really only 3 primary partitions, leaving one available for Ubuntu. If you already have 4 primaries used, you'll need to do some juggling.

Comment: As i opened gparted,it shows warning popup says "Libparted bugfound! : the primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears ok. So that will be used."

Comment: And after showing that popup. It shows the partiton table. And only have free space 500 gb.  Meanwhile in windows. The partitions  are 3 primary and 1 free unallocated

Comment: Im sorry for not telling the details. Before the pop up, there is a question, this one """ LibDev/sdb contains GPT signature  indicating that it has GPT table. However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition as it should. Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesnt understand GPT partitiom tables. Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now msdos partition table. Is this a GPT partition table?"'"' N i clicked yes

Comment: Question: Has the main disk been set up by Windows as a "Basic" disk or a "Dynamic" disk? If it's Dynamic, you won't be able to dual boot. Ubuntu can't boot from a Windows dynamic disk. You'll need to find a second drive. There's another answer here that basically covers the same thing: http://askubuntu.com/a/179309/119639

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and even after searching a lot I still wasn't able to find a working solution. So I started tinkering myself and for me the solution was  the following.

First download the [MiniTool Partition wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) software. When installed open the application and check whether the partition type of the drive where the windows is installed is of the `PRIMARY` type. If not then change the disk type to `PRIMARY` using this minitool partition software and then try to install Ubuntu again. This time it will show the option to "install alongside windows". Don't forget to check the "apply" in the software to apply the changes.

You will have to restart your computer and after restarting it will work without loading into Windows. Read carefully and Do not press any key as you don't want to cancel the operation which the software is working on.

Comment: You really need to work on your post structure. It is very hard to understand you the way you wrote. Please include line breaks and don't use pointless bolding. I've submitted an edit for your post to fix most of your issues.