# I can't see the "Something else" option while installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, usb-installation

While I was updating my Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04, my PC unexpectedly turned off. Then, when I loaded Ubuntu and logged in, I had a clear desktop and couldn't do anything.

I downloaded the installer and booted it with USB and I have a problem. There is no option such as *Update existing Ubuntu partition*, only:

- *Install next to Windows 7*
- *Install instead Windows 7*
- *Use another option*

How do I update my Ubuntu without losing my very important files?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Ubuntu system is now corrupt.

You should delete all the Ubuntu partitions (do a backup of your important files) and install Ubuntu 13.04 in a new partition.

You can find more information to accomplish this on this site:

- [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)
- [How do I set up a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

Comment: How about installing Ubuntu instead of Win7, and then copy these files? Coz I even have a error with grub while loading the PC, and I can not choose any of OS. :P Will it work? I mean, will I have a access to other ext4 partitions?

Comment: You should **first** do a backup of your files, **then** install Ubuntu. When you finish to install Ubuntu, the boot loader should be working fine. If it doesn't, take a look at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)