# dual boot win 7 (pre installed) and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot

friends i am new to ubuntu forum.

please guide me installing ubuntu alongside win 7(preinstaled). I want to run both operating system for now. Please walk me through all the  steps to be carried out to install.
i will be great full to everybody.
Thankyou people.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I should tell you that this is not a forum site, but a Q&A one. Your question has been asked before on [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu). You will find all the necessary information there. So this post, probably, will be [closed as duplicated](http://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions) soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly easy but I suggest making a backup of your important data first. It can always go wrong.

Steps from within Windows (so this will -not- be detailed):

1. Shrink your Windows partition with something like Partition Magic;
2. Leave the space unallocated;
3. [Download the Ubuntu ISO](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for your system specs(32bit or 64bit);
4. Burn it to a DVD (it wont fit on a CD);

Steps after this are not related to Windows:

1. Reboot (with the option in BIOS set to boot from DVD) with the DVD inserted;
2. It will end with a desktop and a popup. Choose "install" to start the installation. Answer all the questions (it will ask for locales, username etc) and, when asked, install Ubuntu in the unallocated space (it will ask for what to do with the installation and this will be an option).

And that is basically it.

It IS very very very easy to do. But you do need a bit of experience in dealing with it but if you keep your eyes open and read what is shown you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To dual-boot the easy way:

1. Download the [Desktop Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (it should be an ISO file) and burn it to a CD.
2. Boot your computer into the CD (you may have to modify the boot order in your BIOS)
3. Choose **Install Ubuntu**.
4. When asked how you want to install Ubuntu, choose **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows XP**.

Follow the installation procedure and you should be fine. You do not need to create any partitions because Ubuntu does that for you. If your computer boots into Windows instead of GRUB, reboot into the CD, choose **Try Ubuntu Before Installing**, and open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then, run `sudo apt-get install boot-repair` followed by `gksudo boot-repair`. Reboot again and Ubuntu should work fine.