# Add windows boot manager entry for Ubuntu on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I installed Ubuntu few months back via the windows installer and use it on a daily basis on my notebook in a dual-boot setup.

I wanted to free up some space in Win7 by removing some programs and I removed Ubuntu related application also accidentaly. I don't know whether it harmed my Ubuntu system or not (I hope it's not) but I know that it removed Ubuntu entry from windows boot loader, so I'm not able to boot to Ubuntu now.

So, my question is how can I add an entry to my windows boot loader on Win7 which points to my Ubuntu system? I tried to solve this issue with EasyBCD 2.2 without any luck.

I run boot-repair and got the following log of my system: [Link to my partition info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5881249/)

If somebody could be so kind to tell me what shoud I do I would highly appriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The key to your question is:** "I installed Ubuntu few months back via the windows installer..."

This is known as WUBI install, and is not the same as dual-boot.

In WUBI, no partitions are created for Ubuntu. Instead, a large file is used inside the Windows system as a virtual partition that stored all your Ubuntu related files. When you removed "Ubuntu related application" Windows deleted that file as well as the entry in the Windows bootloader. Everything related to Ubuntu is gone now.

The best course of action is to install Ubuntu as a true dual-boot by booting directly from a Live USB/DVD and restore your personal files from a backup. I hope you have made backups of your personal files in some external media.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt response! For my personal stuff I use google drive. I'm going to reinstall ubuntu then as a true dual boot! Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. See [How do I set up a dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) as well as Ubuntu official site ubuntu.com for help with dual-boot.