# How to partition for a dual boot

Tags: boot, partitioning

I'm planning to fresh install ubuntu with windows 7 running beside it. Could anyone give me tips on how to do this and which to do first? Also how exactly to partition.

Comment: I'd install Windows first.  The Ubuntu installer will recognise Windows and allow you to install next to it.  Windows wont recognise Ubuntu. Not a major issue as you can fix it but it's easier if you do Ubuntu last.

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous poster pointed you to an [excellent previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) though.

First of all ... Are you starting from scratch (so there is nothing on the disk) or is Win7 already installed.

When I *start from scratch* I like to use an Ubuntu Live CD first to create the partitions (See Below).  I then install Win7 and later I install Ubuntu into the partitions I have setup.

My Boot partition looks something like this.

```
/boot = 1Gb  -> Obviously where all the boot images go
/     = 20Gb -> Ubuntu Root
/win7 = 55Gb -> I Install Win7 here so as my C: drive
/home = 50Gb -> I like a separate partition for my home dir as then if I need to re-install Ubuntu or replace it with another OS then I don't ruin my data
/swap 4Gb
```

In total a 140Gb drive ...

Hope this helps.