# Hosting Ubuntu and Windows on one PC

Tags: windows

I've new years resolution to get to grips with a Linux type of operating system and I think Ubuntu looks the most likely I'd enjoy, as it seems to have good support and a thriving community. However, there is some software for that I rely on Windows for.

Is there a way I could host dual operating systems on the same PC and chose which one I'd like to use at start-up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You may want to backup your data and possibly have a copy on Ubuntu also. For detailed information go to [This Ubuntu Wiki Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) or [This Ask Ubuntu Page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)to help walk you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep dual operating system on your PC, but from my experience (I kept it for last few years), more handy is booting your PC directly from Ubuntu and using Windows whenever you would need it from [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).