# making a triple boot pc win xp win 7 and ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows

OK I am starting all over with a 1TB HD I want to triple boot my pc win xp win 7 and ubuntu 12.04 and also have a left over partition for the gb left after I am done
can this be done

tripleboot

Comment: Best to use only primary partitions for Windows and then leave one primary partition to use as the extended partition for Linux. Then for Ubuntu you can create only logical partitions in the extended partition.

Comment: ok I think you got what I was saying is the linux swap going to be my problem in having a partition HD that all 3 os system can see. because a hd can only have 4 partitions. And if you any instruction on how to set this up it would be much appreciated

Comment: The extended partition is one of the 4 allowed primary partitions. And inside the extended you can have an unlimited number of logical partitions. All Linux partitions work equally well from logical partitions. Windows only boots from a primary, and second installs of Windows always boot from the first install and have no boot files of their own, unless you move boot flag to second install.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by visiting the [Windows Stack Exchange site](https://superuser.com/questions/49685/dual-booting-xp-and-windows-7) for the [setup of XP and Seven](https://superuser.com/questions/460358/dual-booting-with-xp-and-7). Once those work OK, then install Ubuntu 12.04, which will prompt you for the kind of setup you want; instructions for that are at [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) and here in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu). They key is to get Windows set up first.

Comment: +1 for the "Windows first" idea. This OS will write to MBRs and GPTs without giving you a single choice : it'll be better to end the installation with the Linux system, which allows more customizing.