# Choice of operating system

Tags: boot

I have successfully loaded ubuntu alongside windows xp but when I start up my computer there is no choice to boot into windows,why not?

Comment: Please use Boot Repair and post a link to it's log.

Comment: I would love to use Boot Repair but don't have the foggiest idea how to do it :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-with-windows-and-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your grub loader is messed up? Use nano & have a look here: `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` you should see both of your OS's;

A quick search has found this answer on how to repair:
Open the terminal and run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Then install boot repair by running the command

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Launch the boot repair after installing. For example, from the menu, use *System→Administration→Boot-Repair*

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm going to need it.That sounds like rocket science or Martian to me.Why can't any of these damn things be easy!Thanks for trying.

Comment: hmm perhaps it was the way you installed it? I know it's possible to install Ubuntu within Windows, but I am guessing you did not choose this option. When I installed it alongside Windows 7 I got a nice bootloader that lets me choose either Win7 or Ubuntu at bootup.

Comment: I just restarted again & I do get the blue hp invent screen flash up for a second or two.On it it says "<ESC=Boot Menu> <F1+setup>"Should I do something at this stage?

Comment: heronro.......you are correct I did not install it with the windows installer thing.Maybe that's where I went wrong?

Comment: Not really, there are just different ways of installing and using Ubuntu with or in Windows. If you attempt a re-install of Ubuntu using a USB key it will hopefully repair the issue with the bootloader, just make sure not to select the "wipe drive" option if you want to keep XP.

Comment: I hav'nt got a USB key but I might try reinstalling Ubuntu using the windows installer program.That is about the only option I have got because I don't understand all that jargon about grub loaders,boot repairs etc.:-( Do I have to wipe the old copy off first or do something like that?

Comment: With the windows installer you can install Ubuntu as if it were just another application within Windows, but this would not be a dual boot solution. Can you get into Windows OK?

Comment: No I can't & opening a terminal to enter the advice given earlier just results in the demand to enter my password but it won't let me type it!

Comment: when you type the password it won't display it on the screen...