# Can I Dual boot Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I have Ubuntu already installed on my computer that I just bought, and I have a copy of Windows 7. I like the feel of Ubuntu, and plan on trying it out, but I have many Windows-specific applications.

So, my question is, is it possible for me to dual boot Windows from Ubuntu. I understand people usually dual boot Ubuntu from Windows, but I have it the other way around. What do you suggest, or is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, but Windows is known to disregard installations of other operating systems.

You will probably need to edit the Windows 7's Boot Configuration Data (BCD) to add the entry for Ubuntu. The easiest way is to use a BCD editor like EasyBCD: [www.softpedia.com](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml)
After installing Windows, install EasyBCD and add the entry for Ubuntu.

This will make a dual-boot system but will still use the Windows' Boot Manager. If you would like to use GRUB as a boot manager, you can find more info on reinstalling GRUB here: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  See here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 even if Windows 7 was installed first.  [The answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/107539/267266) is very good.

Comment: Thank you. Ubuntu has been installed first, but I see the "Ubuntu First" section of that page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and the steps are listed on this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-with-windows-and-ubuntu/107539#107539).

However if you just want to use windows for a couple of hours to finish some work using a windows specific application and don't want to see any kind of booting issues then I suggest you to go for virtual box. You can install virtual box in your Ubuntu box and then Install windows as a guest OS. The only catch here is you need to have more RAM. If your PC have more than 4GB ram then definitely you can try this