# dual boot from windows 7 can't show ubuntu in boot menu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have windows7 os in my laptop and I want to install ubuntu 12.04 along with windows 7. I have followed the instructions in this link: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/ for dual boot our system. and I have selected the option `install ubuntu inside windows7`. I got message like remove your cd and press enter after installation. When I press Enter it directly goes to my windows7 os without prompting me the option to select diff OS(ubuntu). I have restarted my system even though i didn't get any option to select my ubuntu OS.

Can someone please help me how can I get rid of this problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-with-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: @Minos I have follwed the same instructions as specified in the above link but I ddn't get the last screen of allocating spcae for ubuntu system , before that itself  I got a message `remove your cd and press enter` pleas help

Comment: Did the option say: "install Ubuntu alongside windows 7" or did it really say "install Ubuntu inside Windows 7". Also what happens when you just try it again?

Comment: @Minos It says `install Ubuntu inside Windows 7`

Comment: I'm a bit on a limp here, because I don't think you did what you said. The tutorial you link to says to select the option "something else" and then use a program called EasyBCD to update the windows boatloader. And the regular Ubuntu installer doesn't have an option to install "inside" only "alongside". So I would suggest you start over again and follow the instructions in the tutorial I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

> When I press Enter it directly goes to my windows7 os without prompting me the option to select diff OS(ubuntu). I have restarted my system even though i didn't get any option to select my ubuntu OS.

This means the *windows bootloader* is currently not displaying the **boot menu** for you. Make sure that you have selected:

- Boot default OS after 30 seconds

**If** this does not help, open a *command prompt* as **administrator** and type the command `bcdedit`. Edit your question and add the output of `bcdedit`.

Comment: Thanks for this and but where can I select `Boot default OS after 30 seconds` this option. sorry If i am blunt on this

Comment: @anusha [page 2](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/2/) of the tutorial you linked. Last screenshot of EasyBCD.

Comment: Can't I directly get the boot menu without using EasyBCD as it is extra plugin it seems

Comment: @anusha
If you don't want to use EasyBCD, you need to either
a) use the Ubuntu boot loader
b) configure the Windows boot loader by hand using `bcdedit`
Search for the web for instructions on how to use bcdedit