# My Ubuntu Is 64 Bit On 32 Bit PC?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

My (probably 32bit) PC is low on RAM but the version of Ubuntu is 64-bit. Is there a way to change the architecture without losing my files.

My PC sometimes freezes but Ubuntu Serach Transparent Thing Bar freezes my PC if Software Store is open:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IrajLNA.png]

Photo Is In Lithuania Language So Use:" translate.google.com/ " To Translate Back To English

Comment: You [CPU **is** 64 bit](http://products.amd.com/pages/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=138&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) - otherwise you would not be able to even start the installer. Your issue is likely something else (e.g. lacking graphics drivers - did you try to install additional drivers from the system settings?). Also you should not install 12.10 as it is no longer supported. Get 14.04 instead.

Comment: but im got failure with installer my system cause hardrive failure to put files on windows empty disk

Comment: My samsung empti windows hardrive

Comment: but if i keep my old ver it will be no harddrive failures such as root problems to put files beacuse my dad cant understand how to install 12.10 my family likes this version then new beacuse wubi has new hardrive selections so its easier to find wich drive located than new beacuse is to dificult :( heres photo how it looks like:http://imgur.com/1a2mXRo

Comment: Try to dual boot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported for Windows 8 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-do-i-set-up-a-dual-boot-with-windows-and-ubuntu for Windows7 (or earlier)

Comment: my desktop pc uses windows 8 pro media center

Comment: im put edit on my long message check this photo out!

Comment: WAIT! IN MY PROFILE IM GOT ISO FILES IM CAN USE WUBI ONLY TO DO! IM PUT 32 BIT VER YES! THIS WILL WORK! LOOK AT MY PROFILE TO SEE MY FILES IM GOT mac ver if you want to do! :D thanks! roadmr check my old one its fetch bug if i fail im can use it again if it fail

Comment: im using magic iso so im can extarct wubi only or all files to use ubuntu 12.10 32 bit im will be trying to:use all files

Comment: PC 32Bit Ubuntu 12.10 download take about 1 hour 1 min

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU is not 32-bit. If you have a 64-bit installation, then your CPU is 64-bit. The 64-bit installer will not even boot or run on a 32-bit CPU.

Comment: look at photo you will teel if its high beacuse my pc can froze