# Does Re-installing Ubuntu remove Windows/Other OSes?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader, reinstall

I have a dual boot laptop, and recently install Windows 10 Technical preview on it (also with Windows 7 Installed), but that got rid of the Ubuntu purple boot menu. I want to re-install it, but I don't know if it will overwrite any of the other operating systems. Can someone tell me if it does or doesent (I don't care about losing files on the old Ubuntu (which I cannot load (lost boot menu) ) but I NEED the files on Windows 7.

So, In the end, I just need to know if re-installing Ubuntu (on dual boot with Windows 7 & 10 technical preview) will get rid of Windows 7 And Windows 10 Technical preview.

**Need an answer *Quite Quick!***

*(plus if you have the link to a question that might answer mine, leave that in the comment)*

Answer (score 1):

> So, In the end, I just need to know if re-installing Ubuntu (on dual
>   boot with Windows 7 & 10 technical preview) will get rid of Windows 7
>   And Windows 10 Technical preview.

It depends on how you install Ubuntu. What you want to do is dual boot with Ubuntu. Follow the instructions in the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu) to preserve Windows and add Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Before reinstalling a new Ubuntu you should try to reinstall grub. Sometimes a new installation of Windows erases it.

Anyway a new installation of Ubuntu should not erase existing Windows.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: This topic explains the way to reinstall grub : http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows. The answer given by Carl H redirects to a link explaining how to install the dual boot (if grub's reinstallation does not shows any result).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you install Ubuntu in a partition not being used by either installed copy of Windows, it will not overwrite your Windows installs.  The bootloader installation step of the Ubuntu install should detect your Windows installs and add them to your grub menu (the "purple boot menu").

Answer (score 0):

Just head to the official [Ubuntu Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) documentation and follow instructions there.  That's the least risky of all solutions.

That being said, [always take back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your entire PC (a.k.a. a "System Backup") before you attempt dangerous things like installing Windows 10 preview...  **;-)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**