# repair ubuntu in a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall

It's simple. So, treat it that way..
I'm a newbie to the linux community. I recently messed up my ubuntu trusty installed along with win 7. now, i can't even log in. but it doesn't matter. All i need is to reinstall a fresh copy of ubuntu in that dual boot environment. 
All i need to know are the exact procedures to do it. Not worried over data, have a backup. Please don't ask any TECHNO-WINNIE questions about the current status of my ubuntu. all i need to know is procedure to repair or reinstall it with a live usb. if screenshots available it'd be more understanding..

Arc: Running ubuntu trusty along with win 7.
Status: unable to create session
Cause: accidently deleted power management settings from ->settings.
        so some repositories are deleted along with it.

I'm hoping not to repair but reinstall a fresh copy.

Comment: For a fresh install on a dual boot system, perform the procedure spelled out in the answer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu  Screen shots and all!

Comment: Of course you will have backed up your Windows data before starting anything like this.  When you get to the partitioning screen, it may look different if your current Ubuntu installation is detected.  Be sure not to select any options that involve formatting the whole disk.

Comment: Add the link to screenshots and we will make it available.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for reinstalling is basically the same as the first install, just make sure you format the root partition for a clean install. You can look at this tutorial (http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu.html) for reference.