# Dual-Booting with Windows 7 PC

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install ubuntu on my windows7 PC (64 bit intel corei3) For Dual-Booting. How can I do it? Which version of ubuntu is suitable for my PC?.

Answer (score 0):

Instuctions about dual booting are available on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu).

You can use ubuntu 16.04 LTS version. As an Long Term Support (LTS) you can have it on your system for around 5 years without problems.

Make sure you read the instructions carefully before trying dual booting. And more importantly:

**BACK UP YOUR DATA!!**

This includes the recovery partition if you have a laptop with one. I have used [macrium reflects](http://www.macrium.com/) free tool for that. Another important note here for dual booters. Use windows tools for windows things and linux tools for linux things - do not mix them. (For example use windows disk management to reduce windows partitions not linux tools [ie gparted].)

Also another good precaution step is to create a live USB (that you will use to install anyway) and use the "try ubuntu without installing" option (you need to be able to change bios boot settings to boot from usb). That way your system will load from USB and you can check that the basic staff works (for example wifi connectivity). This way you can be sure to have the ability to solve any minor problem that appears. If something basic doesn't work when trying ubuntu before installing make a new question about it here to be sure you can solve it.