# How can I install Windows alongside an Ubuntu 16.04 installation?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, windows

I need windows 7 or 8 installed alongside Ubuntu 16.04.

Since I just got the computer, I don't really have any important data on it, so if I lose anything, it doesn't really matter.

Can someone give me a tutorial for dual booting Windows on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine?

Comment: @TonyLancer Don’t agree, that’s the other (more common) way. However, question about installing Windows is probably off-topic.

Comment: Where else am I supposed to ask this? This is relevant to Ubuntu.

Comment: @BjornVilhjamsson You are right, the topic here would be "dual booting" Windows with Ubuntu.  The thing is: it is always easier, especially if you're a "n00b" to install Windows first, and Ubuntu second.  The reason is that Windows doesn't acknowledge there are even other OSes in existence.  Ubuntu does.  
As per your own statement, there is nothing important on the machine which means you really don't need to keep Ubuntu.  Install Windows first, then install Ubuntu.  Here is a link to start off: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that that's what I'd have to do, thanks for the link.
Even so, is it even possible to do it my way? If so, I could probably follow a tutorial if there was one. I just don't want to go through the hassle of installing two operating systems again, but if I have to, I will.

Comment: @BjornVilhjamsson There is a similar site called [Super User](https://superuser.com/) where Windows questions are on-topic. However, the link provided by David should help.