# Can I run Ubuntu on Lenevo 3000 N200?

Tags: dual-boot

Can I run Ubuntu on Lenevo 3000 N200 ? 
If so what version of Ubuntu should I use ?
Can I use Ubuntu with Window 7?
Is there any information that I can read before I proceed?

Comment: Yes you can, but you won't like it. Try Lubuntu or UbuntuMATE. There are many videos on Youtube if you want to see them first.

Comment: Should work. [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328), [How can I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/107538), [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1366), [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835) (might not apply), [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795), & [...find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407)

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Can You run Ubuntu on your Lenovo 3000 N200?

[This](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/documents/migr-67706) is where I have seen the configuration of your machine. Also the minimum system requirement for Ubuntu can be found [here on Ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements). According to the site, minimum system requirements for running a desktop version (I'm sure, you want to run **desktop** version of Ubuntu and not the **server version**) are:

1) 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better).

2) 512 MiB RAM (system memory).

3) 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach).

4) VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.

5) Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.

It would be great to have working internet.

But Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and up uses Unity as the default Graphical User Interface while the previous releases used GNOME Panel by default. In order to run Unity the system needs a more capable graphics adapter:

- 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better).
- 1024 MiB RAM (system memory).
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB.

It is suggested to have atleast **1 GB of RAM** to run Ubuntu. If you want to run a lightweight version, you can choose *[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net)* or *[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org)*.

So, yes you can install/run Ubuntu Desktop on your machine.

### 2. Which version you should use?

You can have two options to choose from. If you just want to experience Ubuntu for some time then you can install the latest version which is Ubuntu 16.10.([documentation for Ubuntu 16.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/ReleaseNotes)).
But if you are willing to spend more time with Ubuntu then you should opt for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has the benefit that updates will be provided for much longer period (hence the LTS; Long Term Support) ([documentation for Ubuntu 16.04L LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)).

### 3. Can you use Windows 7 with Ubuntu?

**Yes**, of course you can install Ubuntu with Windows 7. You can use [wubi installer](http://wubi-installer.org/) for that purpose. Please see the answer to ["how can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows). The answer will guide you step by step on installing Ubuntu with Windows 7.

Comment: wubi installer is a very bad choice.

Comment: I have also quoted the question which have nice answers to solve the problem. I'm hopeful that the user will find it helpful.