# Slingtv on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I bought "SlingTV" and am currently running on Ubuntu and was wondering how to run it. It says that it has an error with WINE's application database.

[image]

Comment: Could you add more details on how you installed sling? Have you checked winehq appdb for comparability with the program you instaled? This may be usefull: https://www.reddit.com/r/cordcutters/comments/2v4riq/sling_tv_on_linux/

Comment: Sure (and I will check the link): I downloaded the windows version and installed it normally. I assumed thathat it will run due to wineHQ. I, obviously,  was dumb. Now it prompts me with that.

Comment: So i stumbled across that site before but I skipped it as it talks about home theater and not actually running on desktop.

Comment: Right, but it seems to work regardless. As I understand it, the htpc desktop in this instance is just mirrored to the TV, so it should work on a monitor too. In addition to that link, Archon may be another way. It runs Android APKs in chrome browser. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-chrome-mac-linux-windows/

Comment: Good news bad news:

Good news: it works to a point

Bad news: when it shows a gray screen with its respective icon in the center, it says select folder. Which folder?

Apologies for consistent editing. I tried to hit enter to space, and, well it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of `wine --version` and which version of Windows do you have selected to emulate under Configure Wine?

Comment: My version of Wine is 2.0 The Windows version I am emulating is 8.1

Answer (score 1):

According to everything I've been able to find support is limited to MAC OSX, Windows and Android and IOS apps. While wine emulates Windows, it isn't windows and not all applications work on wine. For future reference check the [Wine HQ app database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) to determine the level of support you can expect from wine for a given app. These levels range from Platinum (very good) to Garbage (exactly what it sounds like). If you mst have compatibility with a given app you can resolve this issue the way I do by either

A) [Dual-booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107538/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-and-ubuntu)

or

B) [Hosting a VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697828/i-am-having-a-problem-installing-windows-on-vm)

I hope this helps.